# Calculating the residual degree of 2 in the cubic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{p})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand the splitting of $2$ in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{p})$ where $p\equiv\pm 1 \operatorname{mod }9$. Putting $\alpha:=\sqrt[3]{p}$ I know that $\{1,\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}{3}\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module and I think that as a ring it its generated by $\alpha$ and $\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}{3}$ i.e. $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}\left[\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}{3}\right]$. I know (using discriminants) that $2$ doesn't ramify and I am trying to figure out what is its residual degree; in order to do that I'm studying the ring $\frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{2\mathcal{O}_K}$ which amounts to studying the ring $\frac{\mathbb{Z}\left[\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}{3}\right]}{(2)}$. Now if $p(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}{3}$ is it true that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}\left[\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}{3}\right]}{(2)}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(2,X^3-p,p(X))}
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[X]}{(\overline{X^3-p},\overline{p(X)})}
$$
where $\overline{p(X)}$ and $\overline{X^3-p}$ are the polynomials taken modulo $2$? If this is true then, knowing an explicit expression of $p(X)$, I would have that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[X]}{(X^3-1,X^3+X^2)}
$$
which I believe is the trivial ring, although I would have to actually prove it.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: $p(X)$ or $p(\alpha,X)$ or $p(t,X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)/3$ **over $\Bbb{Z}[t]/(t^3-p)\cong\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$**

Comment: It's not a good idea to write about primes $p$ and polynomials $p(x)$ in the same setting.

Comment: The problem is that from what I understand the field is not monogenic i.e. the ring of integers is not generated by one element so I can’t (or can I?) study the splitting of 2 by computing how $X³-p$ splits into different factors in $\mathbb{F}_2$